# How to amplify volume level of MediaStream using javascript

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am using video element of html5 for displaying video and audio streaming.

In older version of systems (laptops, pcs, etc), somtimes volume level is not good. so i want to amplify stream audio volume .

I made some hunt but didn't find any feasible solution.

Please provide me some links or some solution so that i can integrate that in my app

Answer (score 0):

you can use [timbre.js](http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/) to add compression ( with gain, ie. amplification ) to the audio of your video track. Something like this:

```
 // the source of your video file
 var src = document.getElementById('video').firstElementChild.src;

 // this will play and loop the audio with increased gain
 var video = T("audio", {loop:true}).load(src, function(res) {

     T("comp", {thresh:-48, knee:30, ratio:24, gain:18}, this).play();

 });
```